# Facebook login not working after exporting android app?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am developing an android app that is integrated with facebook sdk. I get a strange problem. I have copied my key hash value on facebook developer page and my app works perfectly. But whenever I export  exported my android app using eclipse then facebook login does not work. I think it is due to key hash value that has been changed when I export my app. Please help me how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.